# is there a code in R to change the x axis in ggboxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, boxplot

I want to simplify my x-axis by using breaks for the coordinates

[image]

I'm actually using this code:

```
ggline(myr_mass, x = "Latitude", y = "body_mass", color = "Taxa",
       add = c("mean_se", "dotplot"))+
  theme_bw()+
    rotate_x_text(45)
```

Comment: This plot suggests your data is not being read in as numbers. You need to look into how your reading it in (`read.csv`?) and fix that before looking at plotting them. For confirmation, `str(myr_mass)` should show `num` (real/float/numeric/double) or `int` (integer) for your x-axis variable.

Comment: I think you need to convert Latitude to numeric. It is a factor or character at the moment. Try `myr_mass$Latitude <- as.numeric(as.character(myr_mass$Latitude))` then repeat the plot.

Comment: ... and look at how it's being imported/read-in so that you don't have to do that every time and with every (related/similar) dataset.

Comment: You're using the `ggpubr` package?

Comment: I'm using the ggpubr package!

Comment: Check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3418192/8245406).

Comment: I tried to convert to numeri but it's still not working

Comment: My data is numeric but is still not working!